# Is it possible to rename a cookie in nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx

In apache web proxy server we can rename a cookie like

Header edit Set-Cookie "CookieFromApplicationServer*=" "NewCookieName="

RequestHeader edit Cookie "NewCookieName[ ]*=" "CookieFromApplicationServer="

I am looking for an equivalent in nginx web proxy server. Is it possible to rename a cookie through nginx? Experts please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming a cookie implies that you create a new cookie, and delete existing cookie.
Creating a cookie does work. And also if you recreate the same cookie on the same domain, the value will get update. So what you can do is create the new cookie, and update the current cookie with `0 Expiry time.`

Or just simply create a new cookie and don't use the old one.

Below is how you can create the cookie in Nginx.

```
add_header Set-Cookie "<new-name>=<value>;Domain=<domain-name>;Path=<path-name>;Max-Age=<Expire time>";

add_header Set-Cookie "<old-name>=<value>;Domain=<domain-name>;Path=<path-name>;Max-Age=0";
```

Comment: It should be fine in case of response. But request from nginx to application server should contain the original cookie name. I want to this to be some proxy layer.